# Can you ask questions about darknets other than Tor?

Tags: discussion, questions

Does the Tor Stack Exchange site accept questions about other darknets such as I2P, Freenet, etc. What is the site's policy on questions about other darknets? For reference, the site says:

> Tor Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for researchers, developers, and users of Tor. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Tor.

---

I have asked questions regarding onion routing with Tor and garlic routing with I2P. That seem to be fine, but if I ask questions about how I2P works or how Freenet works without saying anything about the Tor network, would that be improper?